# Why do syntax errors make a 8.` run through $PreRead in a TagBox?

Tags: front-end

Modified code from the help file on $Pre:

```
$PreRead =.

SetAttributes[saveinputs, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
saveinputs[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]}; new);
$PreRead = saveinputs;
```

Evaluating:

```
<>
```

then

```
Flatten[inputs]

{<>,8.,RowBox[{Flatten,[,inputs,]}]}
```

If you look at the Cell Expression for the 8. it is actually a TagBox

```
TagBox["8.`", HoldForm]
```

Why does a syntax error cause this?

Example where this causes a problem in code:

```
$PreRead =.

SetAttributes[saveinputs, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
saveinputs[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]};
  If[Unevaluated[new],
   new,
   new);
$PreRead = saveinputs;
```

When evaluating pretty much anything you get:

```
ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse 8.` as Mathematica input.
```

If the test clause of the if statement in the above code does not depend on new then it runs fine.

```
$PreRead =.

SetAttributes[saveinputs, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
saveinputs[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]};
  If[True,
   new,
   new);
$PreRead = saveinputs;
```

The above works fine.

How am I changing new in the test clause to cause this to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "How am I changing new in the test clause to cause this to fail?"

With three arguments, `If[condition,t,f]`, `If` remains unevaluated, i.e., it returns `If[condition,t,f]`, if the condition is neither `True` nor `False`.

Using the four-arguments form, `If[condition,t,f,u]` gives `u` if condition evaluates to neither `True` nor `False` as in your case with `Unevaluated[new]` as the test clause.

So if you change your code to

```
$PreRead =.

SetAttributes[saveinputs, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
saveinputs[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]};If[whatever, new, new, new]);
$PreRead = saveinputs;
```

it works like the example in the docs.

Comment: Sure enough, just needed a TrueQ to make sure it turned out a boolean.